# What is the difference between "meters squared" and "square meters"?

Tags: geometry, terminology, area

So I'm in year 11 and I just had a question about area.

> What is the difference between "meters squared" and "square meters"?

Because all my teachers told me that they are the same thing, but when I googled it, it said there's a difference. So what is that difference?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference.  Some say to-may-to, some say to-mah-to.

Comment: Numerically they are the same.

Answer (score 3):

So out of curiosity, I searched for "square meters vs meters squared" and found [this post](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-square-meters-and-vs-meters-squared/). So is Olivia right?

No. That is a complete posterior extraction.

When people say "$4$ meters squared", practically without exception they mean an area equal to that of a $2\text{ m}\times 2\text{ m}$ square, exactly like "$4$ square meters". A few noobs might mistake it for $(4\text m)^2$, but they would quickly find out the error of their ways.

Answer (score 0):

A [square metre](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_metre) is not the same thing as a "metre square" - although it is true that exactly $1$ square metre is exactly $1$ meter square. But that only works for the numbers $1$ and $0$; no others.

For example, a square that is $2$ metres long and $2$ metres wide has $4$ square metres of area.